# NullPointerExceptions, can't figure this one out

Tags: java, android, exception

### Code:

```
public class ProductsActivity extends Activity {

DbHelper db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_products);

    db = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String listName = intent.getExtras().getString("position");

    List<Products> listOfProducts = db.getAllProductsByList(listName);
    List<String> stringListOfProducts = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfProducts.size(); i++)
        stringListOfProducts.add(listOfProducts.get(i).getProductName());

    ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringListOfProducts);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    lv.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.products, menu);
    return true;
    }

  }
```

### Error:

I'm getting an error on line 37

> lv.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

I have another project which does everything exactly the same and that works fine!

Comment: Do you have a ListView with id `listView2` defined in your `activity_products` xml file?

Comment: oh god ...
I actually checked 3-4 times and to me (at the time!) it looked like I did have it however, it turns out I made it in another project.... I really have to tidy up my eclipse workspace.... Thank you very much friend!

Comment: Most likely your `ListView lv` is the null object. You should check to make sure that `findViewById` is in fact returning what you expect it to.